Jetpack Compose SharedTransitionLayout with AnchoredDraggable
Is there a way to combine the awesomeness of a SharedTransition/AnimatedContent with the dragging of an AnchoredDraggable, so that the transition happens as you drag the element as well as just clicking on it?  I'm trying to make a media player that is expandable with both a click event and on drag.  I've include a link to a short clip of the SharedTransition implementation and a similar one that I did with AnchoredDraggable, but I would like to combine the two.  I've seen a similar effect in other apps, but none that I can find at the moment.
The sample clip of the AnchoredDraggable just has both composables drawn always, but the one is transparent and it's transparency goes away as you drag and the other one becomes transparent at the same rate.  This does cause an issue where you can't click on the bottom nav, since the transparent composable is over the nav, but transparent.
SharedTransition: https://imgur.com/a/LIe1zM8
AnchoredDraggable: https://imgur.com/a/zqdi6lD
@OptIn(ExperimentalSharedTransitionApi::class)
@Composable
fun AnchoredDraggableContent(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var miniPlayerHeight by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    Logger.d { "BEERS - miniPlayerHeight: $miniPlayerHeight" }

    var showFull by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    SharedTransitionLayout(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        AnimatedContent(
            targetState = showFull,
            label = "basic_transition"
        ) { targetState ->
            when {
                !targetState -> {
                    MiniItem(
                        animatedVisibilityScope = this@AnimatedContent,
                        sharedTransitionScope = this@SharedTransitionLayout,
                        onShowFull = { showFull = true }
                    )
                }
                else -> {
                    FullItem(
                        animatedVisibilityScope = this@AnimatedContent,
                        sharedTransitionScope = this@SharedTransitionLayout,
                        onShowMini = { showFull = false }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

const val KEY_CONTAINER = "KEY_CONTAINER"
const val KEY_CLOSE_MINIMIZE = "KEY_CLOSE_MINIMIZE"
const val KEY_IMAGE = "KEY_IMAGE"
const val KEY_TITLE = "KEY_TITLE"
const val KEY_SUBTITLE = "KEY_SUBTITLE"
const val KEY_PROGRESS_INDICATOR = "KEY_PROGRESS_INDICATOR"
const val KEY_LEFT_BUTTON = "KEY_LEFT_BUTTON"
const val KEY_MIDDLE_BUTTON = "KEY_MIDDLE_BUTTON"
const val KEY_RIGHT_BUTTON = "KEY_RIGHT_BUTTON"

@OptIn(ExperimentalSharedTransitionApi::class)
@Composable
private fun MiniItem(
    animatedVisibilityScope: AnimatedVisibilityScope,
    sharedTransitionScope: SharedTransitionScope,
    onShowFull: () -> Unit
) {
    with(sharedTransitionScope) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(70.dp)
                .offset {
                    IntOffset(x = 0, y = 3120 - 168 - 280 - 245) // full view height - system nav - app nav - player height)
                }
                .sharedBounds(
                    sharedContentState = rememberSharedContentState(key = KEY_CONTAINER),
                    animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
                    boundsTransform = { _, _ ->
                        spring(
                            dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioNoBouncy,
                            stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow
                        )
                    }
                )
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface)
                .clickable { onShowFull() }
        ) {
            HorizontalDivider()
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(vertical = 8.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {},
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .sharedElement(
                            state = rememberSharedContentState(key = KEY_CLOSE_MINIMIZE),
                            animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
                            boundsTransform = { _, _ ->
                                spring(
                                    dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioNoBouncy,
                                    stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow
                                )
                            }
                        )
                ) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Close, contentDescription = null)
                }
                AsyncImage(
                    model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                        .data(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                        .crossfade(true)
                        .build(),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(54.dp)
                        .aspectRatio(1f)
                        .sharedElement(
                            state = rememberSharedContentState(key = KEY_IMAGE),
                            animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
                            boundsTransform = { _, _ ->
                                spring(
                                    dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioNoBouncy,
                                    stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow
                                )
                            }
                        )
                        .clip(MaterialTheme.shapes.medium)
                        .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant),
                    alignment = Alignment.TopCenter,
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                )
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Awesome title text here",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .sharedBounds(
                                sharedContentState = rememberSharedContentState(key = KEY_TITLE),
                                animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
                                boundsTransform = { _, _ ->
                                    spring(
                                        dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioNoBouncy,
                                        stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow
                                    )
                                }
                            )
                            .skipToLookaheadSize(),
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                        maxLines = 1,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = "Awesome subtitle text here",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .sharedBounds(
                                sharedContentState = rememberSharedContentState(key = KEY_SUBTITLE),
                                animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
                                boundsTransform = { _, _ ->
                                    spring(
                                        dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioNoBouncy,
                                        stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow
                                    )
                                }
                            )
                            .skipToLookaheadSize(),
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                        maxLines = 1,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium
                    )
                    LinearProgressIndicator(
                        progress = { 0.25f },
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .height(2.dp)
                            .sharedBounds(
                                sharedContentState = rememberSharedContentState(key = KEY_PROGRESS_INDICATOR),
                                animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
                                boundsTransform = { _, _ ->
                                    spring(
                                        dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioNoBouncy,
                                        stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow
                                    )
                                }
                            ),
                        strokeCap = StrokeCap.Round
                    )
                }
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {},
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .sharedElement(
                            state = rememberSharedContentState(key = KEY_LEFT_BUTTON),
                            animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
                            boundsTransform = { _, _ ->
                                spring(
                                    dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioNoBouncy,
                                    stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow
                                )
                            }
                        )
                ) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.SkipPrevious, contentDescription = null)
                }
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {},
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .sharedElement(
                            state = rememberSharedContentState(key = KEY_MIDDLE_BUTTON),
                            animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
                            boundsTransform = { _, _ ->
                                spring(
                                    dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioNoBouncy,
                                    stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow
                                )
                            }
                        )
                ) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.PlayArrow, contentDescription = null)
                }
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {},
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .sharedElement(
                            state = rememberSharedContentState(key = KEY_RIGHT_BUTTON),
                            animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
                            boundsTransform = { _, _ ->
                                spring(
                                    dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioNoBouncy,
                                    stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow
                                )
                            }
                        )
                ) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.SkipNext, contentDescription = null)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalSharedTransitionApi::class)
@Composable
private fun FullItem(
    animatedVisibilityScope: AnimatedVisibilityScope,
    sharedTransitionScope: SharedTransitionScope,
    onShowMini: () -> Unit
) {
    with(sharedTransitionScope) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .systemBarsPadding()
                .sharedBounds(
                    sharedContentState = rememberSharedContentState(key = KEY_CONTAINER),
                    animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
                    boundsTransform = { _, _ ->
                        spring(
                            dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioNoBouncy,
                            stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow
                        )
                    }
                )
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp, Alignment.CenterVertically),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Column {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    IconButton(
                        onClick = { onShowMini() }
                    ) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowDown, contentDescription = null)
                    }
                    PrimaryTabRow(
                        selectedTabIndex = 0,
                        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                        divider = {}
                    ) {
                        Tab(
                            text = { Text("Player") },
                            selected = true,
                            onClick = {}
                        )
                        Tab(
                            text = { Text("Playing Next") },
                            selected = false,
                            onClick = {}
                        )
                    }
                    IconButton(onClick = {}) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.MoreVert, contentDescription = null)
                    }
                }
                HorizontalDivider()
            }
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                AsyncImage(
                    model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                        .data(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                        .crossfade(true)
                        .build(),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(250.dp)
                        .aspectRatio(1f)
                        .sharedElement(
                            state = rememberSharedContentState(key = KEY_IMAGE),
                            animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
                            boundsTransform = { _, _ ->
                                spring(
                                    dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioNoBouncy,
                                    stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow
                                )
                            }
                        )
                        .clip(MaterialTheme.shapes.medium)
                        .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant),
                    alignment = Alignment.TopCenter,
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                )
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Awesome supertitle text here",
                        modifier = Modifier.skipToLookaheadSize(),
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = "Awesome title text here",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .sharedBounds(
                                sharedContentState = rememberSharedContentState(key = KEY_TITLE),
                                animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
                                boundsTransform = { _, _ ->
                                    spring(
                                        dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioNoBouncy,
                                        stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow
                                    )
                                }
                            )
                            .skipToLookaheadSize(),
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = "Awesome subtitle text here",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .sharedBounds(
                                sharedContentState = rememberSharedContentState(key = KEY_SUBTITLE),
                                animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
                                boundsTransform = { _, _ ->
                                    spring(
                                        dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioNoBouncy,
                                        stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow
                                    )
                                }
                            )
                            .skipToLookaheadSize(),
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall
                    )
                }
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    IconButton(
                        onClick = {},
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .sharedElement(
                                state = rememberSharedContentState(key = KEY_LEFT_BUTTON),
                                animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
                                boundsTransform = { _, _ ->
                                    spring(
                                        dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioNoBouncy,
                                        stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow
                                    )
                                }
                            )
                    ) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.SkipPrevious, contentDescription = null)
                    }
                    IconButton(onClick = {}) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Replay10, contentDescription = null)
                    }
                    IconButton(
                        onClick = {},
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .sharedElement(
                                state = rememberSharedContentState(key = KEY_MIDDLE_BUTTON),
                                animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
                                boundsTransform = { _, _ ->
                                    spring(
                                        dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioNoBouncy,
                                        stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow
                                    )
                                }
                            )
                    ) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.PlayArrow, contentDescription = null)
                    }
                    IconButton(onClick = {}) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Forward10, contentDescription = null)
                    }
                    IconButton(
                        onClick = {},
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .sharedElement(
                                state = rememberSharedContentState(key = KEY_RIGHT_BUTTON),
                                animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
                                boundsTransform = { _, _ ->
                                    spring(
                                        dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioNoBouncy,
                                        stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow
                                    )
                                }
                            )
                    ) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.SkipNext, contentDescription = null)
                    }
                }
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp, Alignment.CenterVertically)
                ) {
                    LinearProgressIndicator(
                        progress = { 0.25f },
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .sharedBounds(
                                sharedContentState = rememberSharedContentState(key = KEY_PROGRESS_INDICATOR),
                                animatedVisibilityScope = animatedVisibilityScope,
                                boundsTransform = { _, _ ->
                                    spring(
                                        dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioNoBouncy,
                                        stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow
                                    )
                                }
                            ),
                        strokeCap = StrokeCap.Round
                    )
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = "00:00",
                            modifier = Modifier.skipToLookaheadSize()
                        )
                        Text(
                            text = "04:34",
                            modifier = Modifier.skipToLookaheadSize()
                        )
                    }
                }
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    IconButton(onClick = {}) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.LooksOne, contentDescription = null)
                    }
                    IconButton(onClick = {}) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.LooksTwo, contentDescription = null)
                    }
                    IconButton(onClick = {}) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Looks3, contentDescription = null)
                    }
                    IconButton(onClick = {}) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Looks4, contentDescription = null)
                    }
                    IconButton(onClick = {}) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Looks5, contentDescription = null)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

